# renderToPipeableStream pipe throw no event

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express, pipe, server-side-rendering

i try to use the renderToPipeableStream function from React18. It works but i don't can handle the pipe good.

This is the important part of my code, i guess. html is a array of strings of the html. I split the string in the middle, where i want to put the react code.

```
server.get("/", (req: any, res: any) => {  
    res.write(html[0] + '<div id="root">')
    const stream = ReactDomServer.renderToPipeableStream(
       <App />
    ).pipe(res, { end: false })
    stream.on("end", () => {
        res.write('</dev>' + html[1])
        res.end()
    })
})
```

the problem is that `stream.on("end"` doesn't fire. But i want this because without is the html code not complete. The browser ignore that but this is not good so.

Comment: Were you able to solve this ? If yes, can you please share the working solution

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
  const stream = renderToPipeableStream(jsx, {
    onAllReady() {
      res.end(`</div></body></html>`);
    },
  });

  stream.pipe(res, { end: false });
  res.flush();
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertopipeablestream

Comment: where did you find the res.flush function?

Comment: This solution worked for me , but i was wondering whether it is the right approach as React doc says "If you don't want streaming, use this instead of onShellReady."

Comment: The pipe function only takes 1 argument as you can see here https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/react-dom/src/server/ReactDOMFizzServerNode.js#L90

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the issue with following code

```
  const app = renderToPipeableStream(<App />);

  res.type('html');

  res.write(getDocumentHead(req, res)); //Custom function to construct header html

  app.pipe(res, {end: false});

  res.write(getDocumentEnd(req, res)); //Custom function to construct scripts

  res.end();
```